# floating in div in ie 7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, floating

How to avoid the gap between - highlighted as circle

`<div> 
     <SPAN style="float:right"><INPUT type="text"><LABEL>right</LABEL></SPAN>
     <SPAN style="float:left"><INPUT type="checkbox"><LABEL >left</LABEL></SPAN>
     </div>`

[image]

facing this problem in IE 7 only

Comment: Is this all the styling you got? What does the DIV styling look like? Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't separate in span's and float the DIV left...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ8B/4/

I tested in IE7...
BTW inline css is awful =(

or like this (don't prefer this way ...)

Example2: http://jsfiddle.net/3DQ8B/127/

Comment: I need right one need to come first in the DOM structure, for tab navigation